# Which one should I consider to calculate probability (P) of independence events? is it P or (1-P)?

Tags: probability

I have doubt about calculating probability of independent events.
Let's say that the probability of a wafer contains a large particle of contamination is p and that the wafers are independent; that is, the probability that a wafer contains a large particle is not dependent on the characteristics of any of the other wafers. If 15 wafers are analyzed, then I want to measure the probability that no large particles are found.

Should I consider here 1-p^15 as the probability or (1-p)^15 & why

Comment: The difference between these two is the difference between the phrases "*It is not the case that all have contamination*" $1-(p^{15})$...  versus "*Every wafer does not have contamination*" $(1-p)^{15}$.  Compare the scenario of where two of the wafers were contaminated.  That case would have been included in the first but not in the second.

Comment: To expand a little on JMoravitz's comment. Number the wafers. The probability that #1 is contaminated is $p$. The probability that #1 and #2 are both contaminated is $p\cdot p = p^2$, etc. The probability that all 15 are contaminated is thus $p^{15}$. then $1-p^{15}$ is the probability of the opposite event. i.e., that at least one of the wafers is not contaminated. On the other hand, the probability that #1 is not contaminated is $1-p$, that #1 and #2 are both not contaminated is $(1-p)(1-p)$, etc. The probability that all 15 are not contaminated is $(1-p)^{15}$.